# asp.net access document.forms[0].controlD

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio

I have problem with access any asp control by JQuery. I know there are other options to do that, but I am wonderring what I am doing wrong. This is simple asp.net website:

```
         <head runat="server">  
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <title></title>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <form id="form1" runat="server">  
        <div id = "mydiv">  
            <input id="btnInit" type="button" value="button" />  
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />  
        </div>  
            <script>  
             jQuery(window).ready(function () {  
                 var form = document.forms[0];  
             });  
         </script>    
        </form>  
    </body>
```

In Jquery function i should have access to asp.net button by ID (Button2), but i do not have. I try :
Button2,
document.form1.Button2,
document.forms[0].Button2, 
and visual studio doesn't see it. If I debug website by firebug, i can get Button2 by ID, but not in VS. What is interesting "form1.btnInit" works, but it is not asp.net control.

I spend all night on that and I still do no know. Any help?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to get the button and it's ID. It is working for me.

```
document.forms[0].Button2.id

alert("Button ID = " + document.forms[0].Button2.id);
```

Comment: OP has clearly mentiond `I know there are other options to do that, but I am wonderring what I am doing wrong`

Comment: document.forms[0] doesn't see Button2, and this is the problem

Comment: document.forms[0] also should has some additional methods (beside bascics) but it does not. It looks like vs doesn't see document.forms[0]

Answer (score -1):

So you are unable to access the button like this?

```
  var $button = $('#Button2');
```

Alternatively you could add a class to the button and access it using that instead:

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" class="button" />
```

Then access it like this:

```
  var $button = $('.button');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: OP has clearly mentiond `I know there are other options to do that, but I am wonderring what I am doing wrong`

Comment: @Jashwant I am confused as to the problem then, maybe they need to make the question a bit clearer. The way i read the question was that they were unable to access the button using jQuery so i provided them with two options. What is the actual problem?

Comment: This approach is ok. But typing - Button2. -  in visual studio I should have access to intellisense. Some time ago It worked, but not now. Mayby position where I declare <script>, nothing helps. I should mention that intellisense for btnInit appears correctly.